# What is the correct way to position controls in a RelativeLayout so that it displays the same

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resolution

What is the correct way to position controls in a RelativeLayout so that it displays the same  irrespective of Device Resolution.I guess this is clear enough,If we use `dp` values in giving margins like `android:layout_marginTop="17dp"` It displays at different places on mdpi,xhdpi,hdpi.

Can someone give a full fledged guenine solution to it? Thanks

Comment: hi nezam. just see this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Comment: Actually, `dp` *is* the correct way of doing this. `dp` and `dip` are the same, meaning device-independent pixels. 17dp should should a margin of 17/160th of an inch, regardless of screen resolution. So if you run it on an xhdpi screen, it would be translated into 34 pixels on the screen.
Do you actually have all those devices, or are you testing in emulator?

Comment: @Nezam, please post some pictures of your controls at different places. It would help to answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have different layouts for different screen sizes. For example for xhdpi screens you create layout-xhdpi folder and put layout.xml for xhdpi screens in there. The same for other screen sizes. There is no way to have one layout looking exactly the same on all displays.

See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Different layouts for different screen sizes, ok. But xhdpi does not signal an screen size, rather a type of density. You should use layout-large/xlarge instead of layout-xhdpi. From the doc page you mentioned: "Usually, you should use the **size and orientation qualifiers** to provide alternative **layout resources** and use the **density qualifiers** to provide alternative **bitmap drawable resources**."