# Screen size Compatibility with Samsung Galaxy S3 and Nexus One

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am trying to create an application that I want to run on both *Samsung Galaxy S3* and the *Nexus One*. But later I came to know that both the devices comes in the normal screen size. How can I make the layouts that fits both the devices?

What type of folders should be created and any entry in the menifest for that folders..?

Comment: a similar question asked few minutes ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640462/what-is-the-correct-way-to-position-controls-in-a-relativelayout-so-that-it-disp

Comment: Is it about the HTC Nexus one?

Comment: on the one which is available in the sdk..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Samsung galaxy s3 - 4.8 inches(Normal screen)
Resolution - 720 * 1280 
XHDPI**

And

**Nexus one -
3.7 inches(Normal)
480 * 800 
HDPI**

A single layout(**normal**) should be fine for both the devices . You can create different set of  images for both as one is **hdpi** and other is **xhdpi**.

Edit : Adding the example table

```
MDPI    X Large 10.1 inches 1280w * 800h(landscape) Samsung Tablet
MDPI    Large   7 inches    1024h * 600w    HTC Flyer
MDPI    Large   7 inches    976h * 600 w    Samsung  GT P6620
```

Comment: ok thanks.. and then what for tabs?? will they also use the xhdpi images??

Comment: There are two categories of tabs - The 7 inch tab (HTC Flyer and  Samsung  GT P6620 types ) and the 10.1 inch tab (the Samsung galaxy tablet.) Both of them come under XLARGE category. And their resolutions are different . Added a table in my answer.

Comment: Sorry i wanted to write both come under Large and X Large as given in the table.

Comment: i have created images for both hdpi and xhdpi but still i am getting the same output for my galaxy s3 and nexus one.. any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is it the background image. What is the resolution ? What is the PPI for the image?

Comment: yes its a background image the resolution that i have create for the nexus one are 140(w) 30(h) and for the galaxy s3 the resolution are 220(w) 45(h) but when i try to run the code i get the images that are of 140 x 30

Comment: Nexus one - use 480 * 800 px bg image . And for S3 use 720 * 1280 px bg image .  Use a Relative layout for the background and use android : background ... hope this helps

Comment: I am using the same but when i run the application i get the same images on both the devices

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23755/discussion-between-anukool-and-abhishek)